# How do I get Seam URLs resolved in the back end?

Tags: java, seam, freemarker

We've got the first of many pages that are going to be generated not by Seam but by FreeMarker. FreeMarker has no way to process an <s:link> but we need to have links within the page that link over to Seam pages within the same application.

What I would like to be able to do is process what would be expressed as the s:link's view="/something.xhtml" or action="#{testClass.test}" from the back end so I could get a URL out, put it into the hash for FreeMarker, and FreeMarker can just insert it into the page just like any other text.

The question is, how do I do that? What Seam functions would I use to do that conversion?

Alternatively, if your answer is, "read the source stupid," please tell me where I should be looking for the source that powers the  tag. I thought of that myself but due to my unfamiliarity with Seam, JSF, etc. I haven't been able to figure out where I should be looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite hard, I think. The logic you are looking for is sparse in several classes and the final html that comes out from `s:link` depends on what happens during the entire JSF render response phase.

Most of the code that defines how action and view attributes are rendered is in `org.jboss.seam.ui.component.UISeamCommandBase`. I suggest that you start putting some breakpoint in the `getUrl()` method of this class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We ended up that same place but it took us a while to find it. Now I've got to figure out how it actually works.